# How can i format data template items into a table like appearance?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datatemplate

I am trying to display dynamically created data template items (bound to objects) into a table format.  Both my stack panel and wrap panels will not format how they did when I originally used buttons.  I am led to believe that my panel controls are not actually formatting the items that are inside of them.

Here are a few relevant samples of my code:

Code behind main window c#

```
int numTapeSlots = 16;
public ObservableCollection<Tape> topTapes;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        topTapes = new ObservableCollection<Tape>();           
        topTapeSlots.ItemsSource = topTapes;            

        //Create Buttons Top Tray
        for (int i = 1; i <= (numTapeSlots / 2); i++)
        {
            topTapes.Add(new Tape(i));
        }
     }
```

xaml

```
<Window.Resources>
  <DataTemplate x:Key="TapeSlot">
    <Border  MouseUp="Border_MouseUp"
             BorderBrush="Black"
             BorderThickness="5">
      <Grid>
        <TextBlock x:Name="slotLocation"
                   Text="{Binding Path=tapeLocation}"
                   Height="25"
                   Width="30" />

      </Grid>
    </Border>
  </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>

<WrapPanel x:Name="wpTopTray"
           Grid.Column="1"
           Margin="20,20,20,20"
           VerticalAlignment="Top">
  <ItemsControl Name="topTapeSlots"
                ItemTemplate="{StaticResource TapeSlot}" />
</WrapPanel>
```

Note: WrapPanel worked fine with buttons

What happens now is that the objects are displayed vertically in a line straight down.  It is almost ignoring the wrapPanel control properties.

Comment: What is your issue? ItemsControl does not format items into WarpPanel?

Comment: Thanks for catching that.  I updated the question and added the problem to the bottom.  Essentially it just displays the objects running straight down the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you should do is use ItemsPanel:

```
        <ItemsControl Name="topTapeSlots" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource TapeSlot}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <WrapPanel/>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        </ItemsControl>
```

Comment: Thank you for this easy and functional response.  I just switched my ordering around and this works great and saved me hours of trying out every control element.